# tkinter enabling a list of buttons, but only one(the last one) responds

Tags: python, tkinter, config, state

I'm having this little nasty problem for which i'm afraid the answer is just to easy to think about in python 3 with tkinter.

So i'm making this on-screen-keyboard which I want to be enabled whenever I push the "enterCountryBtn", however it only enables one button/"key" from the kybrd_list.

The question is simple; How can I make sure that the complete list is enabled whenever i push "enterCountryBtn"?

This is the part of code where my problems seem to occur:

```
def countryCommand():
    keyboardButtons['state']=tk.NORMAL
    print("country")


kybrd_list = [
'q','w','e','r','t','y','...']

ro = 2
co = 0

for k in kybrd_list:
     *A bunch of stuff goes here*
     keyboardButtons=tk.Button(root, text=k, width=5, relief=rel2, command=cmd2, state=tk.DISABLED
     *and some more stuff here*

enterCountryBtn = tk.Button(root, width=30, text="enter Country", command=countryCommand)
enterCountryBtn.grid(row=7, column=0)
```

thanks in advance,
Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `keyboardButtons` a list:

```
def countryCommand():
    for button in keyboardButtons:
        button['state']=tk.NORMAL

keyboardButtons = []
for k in kybrd_list:
    ...
    keyboardButtons.append(tk.Button(root, text=k, width=5, relief=rel2, command=cmd2, state=tk.DISABLED))
    ...
```

---

Here is a runnable example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
kybrd_list = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','...']
def onclick(k):
    def click():
        print(k)
    return click

class SimpleGridApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.keyboardButtons = []
        for i, k in enumerate(kybrd_list):
            button = tk.Button(root, text=k, width=5, relief='raised',
                               command=onclick(k), state=tk.DISABLED)
            button.grid(row=i, column=0)
            self.keyboardButtons.append(button)

        self.enterCountryBtn = tk.Button(
            root, width=30, text="enter Country", command=self.countryCommand)
        self.enterCountryBtn.grid(row=7, column=0)            
    def countryCommand(self):
        for button in self.keyboardButtons:
            button['state']=tk.NORMAL

root = tk.Tk()
app = SimpleGridApp(root, title='Hello, world')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is the right direction to go, however this gives me this error: **tk.Button["state"]=tk.NORMAL TypeError: "NoneType" object does not support item assignment.** Normally I would solve this by putting the .grid attribute (which is causing this error in my believe) in the next line, however this attribute isn't supported by the keyboardButtons list, so i'm unsure how to implement this part correctly. Sorry, still a beginner in python.

Comment: The error is saying that Python is reaching the line `button['state']=tk.NORMAL` with `button` equal to `None`. As you mentioned, it is probably because `grid()` is returning `None` and you are doing something like `keyboardButtons.append(tk.Button(...).grid())`. The solution is to define the button first: `button = tk.Button(...)`, call `button.grid(...)`, and then append: `keyboardButtons.append(button)`. I've added a runnable example for clarity.